# Como pegar o valor de um input dentro de um <td> em jquery

Tags: jquery, html, input

Ola,
Tenho a seguinte tabela em html

```
<table style="display:none;" id="tableTime">  
        <tr>
            <td class="hora">08:00</td>
            <td class="eventoAgenda" id="0800"></td>
            <td class="idEvento" id="id0800"></td>
            <td class="statusVerde"> <input name="status" type="checkbox" ></input> </td>
        </tr>
```

Como faço pra pegar o `<input>` que esta dentro da `<td class="statusVerde>` em jquery??

Tentei algo similar a isto:

```
$('#tableTime tr #statusVerde input #status')
```

mas obviamente não deu certo

Comment: `$("#tableTime input[name='status'")` para acessar pelo name do input.

Comment: e se a tabela for dinamica? tipo existir varios imput com o mesmo nome? como posso pega o valor de cada um? em javascrip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione `id="status"` ao `input`. Veja funcionando:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = $('#status').val();
  alert(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="display:none;" id="tableTime">
  <tr>
    <td class="hora">08:00</td>
    <td class="eventoAgenda" id="0800"></td>
    <td class="idEvento" id="id0800"></td>
    <td class="statusVerde">
      <input name="status" id="status" type="checkbox" value="teste"></input>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Ou pelo atributo `name`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = $('input[name="status"]').val();
  alert(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="display:none;" id="tableTime">
  <tr>
    <td class="hora">08:00</td>
    <td class="eventoAgenda" id="0800"></td>
    <td class="idEvento" id="id0800"></td>
    <td class="statusVerde">
      <input name="status" type="checkbox" value="teste"></input>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

**Referência:**

[How to set value of input text using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611170/how-to-set-value-of-input-text-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa inicializar um atributo ao seu `input` por exemplo `<input name="status" id="statusAqui" type="checkbox">` após isso selecione ele com o jQuery `$('#statusAqui')`.